# Como imprimir datos en un textBox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo este código, quiero saber como hacer que los datos se imprima en el textBox cunado seleccione un RadioButton y le de click en guardar

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    String[] Nombre = new string[100];
    String[] ApPaterno = new string[100];
    String[] Folio = new string[100];
    String[] Sexo = new string[100];
    String[] ApMaterno = new string[100];
    int[] año = new int[100];
    int[] mes = new int[100];
    int[] dia = new int[100];

    int i = 0;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radio_Guardar.Checked == true)
        {
            Nombre[i] = textBox_nombre.Text;
            ApPaterno[i] = textBox_Paterno.Text;
            ApMaterno[i] = textBox_Materno.Text;
            año[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_año.Text);
            mes[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Mes.Text);
            dia[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Dia.Text);

            Folio[i] = (i + 1) + " ";

            label_Folio.Text = Folio[i];

            if (radio_Masculino.Checked == true)
            {
                Sexo[i] = "F";
            }
            if (radio_Femenino.Checked == true)
            {
                Sexo[i] = "M";
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Su nombre es : " + "\n " + Nombre[i] + " " + "\n" + "Apellido Paterno : " + " " + "\n" + ApPaterno[i] + " " + "\n" + "Apellido Materno: " + " " + "\n" + ApMaterno[i] + " " + "\n" + "Sexo:" + Sexo[i] + " " + "\n" + "Folio: " + Folio[i] + " " + "\n" + "año" + " " + año[i] + " " + " \n" + "El mes es :" + mes[i] + " " + "\n" + "Dia: "+dia[i]);

            if (radio_Imprimir.Checked==true)
            {


            }

            //Avanzar el apuntador
            i++; 
        }



    }

    private void radio_Imprimir_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu problema es hacer TextBox.Text = "hola"?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Por que no me imprime nada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/240383/por-que-no-me-imprime-nada)

Answer (score 0):

Una manera sencilla de hacerlo:

```
bool clickbtn = false;
```

si la variable clickbtn paso por el evento del boton entonces sera true y despues haces:

```
if(Radiobutton1.checked == true && clickbtn == true)
{
  Textbox.Text = //tu variable o datos del message aqui
}
```

Comment: No termino de entender esta respuesta. Si esto pasa cuando apreto el boton, ya sabe que el boton fue apretado. Me parece que lo unico que quiere saber OP es hacer textbox.text = texto

Comment: la respuesta esta en base a la pregunta, deberias de leerla, pero si con lo que comentas se resuelve, deberias de ponerla como respuesta.

Comment: Por eso se lo deje como comentario, porque para mi tiene una confusion por ese lado. Por otro lado, donde pondrias clickbtn = true? dentro del evento click del boton? que es donde chequea el radiobutton?

Comment: es logico que iria dentro del evento del boton para ponerlo en true ya que se inicializa en false posterior a eso se pondria la condicion y si la condicion es true en ambos casos del radionutton y la variable, entonces manda el texto al textbox.

Comment: Por eso te lo marcaba.. si esta dentro del evento del boton, y ahi es donde chequea el radiobutton, entonces ya sabe que apreto el boton ;)