# Por que no me imprime nada

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Por que no me imprime nada en el richTextBox

```
    String[] Nombre = new string[100];
    String[] ApPaterno = new string[100];
    String[] Folio = new string[100];
    String[] Sexo = new string[100];
    String[] ApMaterno = new string[100];
    int[] año = new int[100];
    int[] mes = new int[100];
    int[] dia = new int[100];

    int i = 0;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radio_Guardar.Checked == true)
        {
            Nombre[i] = textBox_nombre.Text;
            ApPaterno[i] = textBox_Paterno.Text;
            ApMaterno[i] = textBox_Materno.Text;
            año[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_año.Text);
            mes[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Mes.Text);
            dia[i] = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Dia.Text);

            Folio[i] = (i + 1) + " ";

            label_Folio.Text = Folio[i];

            if (radio_Masculino.Checked == true)
            {
                Sexo[i] = "F";
            }
            if (radio_Femenino.Checked == true)
            {
                Sexo[i] = "M";
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Su nombre es : " + "\n " + Nombre[i] + " " + "\n" + "Apellido Paterno : " + " " + "\n" + ApPaterno[i] + " " + "\n" + "Apellido Materno: " + " " + "\n" + ApMaterno[i] + " " + "\n" + "Sexo:" + Sexo[i] + " " + "\n" + "Folio: " + Folio[i] + " " + "\n" + "año" + " " + año[i] + " " + " \n" + "El mes es :" + mes[i] + " " + "\n" + "Dia: " + dia[i]);


            if (radio_Imprimir.Checked == true )
            {

                for (i = 0; i < 100;i++)
                {

                    richTextBox1.Text += (i + 1) + "nombre" + Nombre[i];
                }
            }


            //Avanzar el apuntador
            i++; 
        }




    }
```

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo y avanzas paso a paso, puedes ver que la ejecucion ingresa por los if que valida los checkbox `radio_Guardar` y `radio_Imprimir` ?

Comment: El radio_Guardar envia un messagebox de los datos que se ingresaron y el radio_imprir debe imprimir los datos en un richTextBox con el boton aceptar pero no me imprime ningún dato

Comment: El problema es que estas usando la variable i por todos lados y esta definida a nivel de la clase. Entonces el for i la manda a 100.. y ya no sirve mas...